# A watermelon is divided into three parts to be served to guests. Is the melon singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, expressions

say that a watermelon is divided into three parts to be served to the guests. I should say "would you like some melons" or "would you like a melon"? I should say "the melon is sweet" or "the melons are sweet"? Which one is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only **one watermelon**, no matter how many pieces it is in, or how many slices you take from it. It is singular. If you asked the guests if they would like a **melon**, they would think you are offering them a honeydew, not watermelon slices. You would never say it that way. In US Southern speech (at least), you would ask the guests if they would like **some watermelon**, implicitly making the case that they will be having more than one slice, not more than one watermelon. To refer to the sweetness of the watermelon as a whole, or the individual slices, you would say, *"The watermelon is sweet."*

Comment: If some bananas are sliced and then served to guests. I should say, "would you like some bananas" or "would you like some banana"?

Comment: The second is more clear, but in speech both are used. It works this way because bananas are small and conceivably one person could eat a few, whereas it's very rare one person could eat an entire watermelon.

Comment: Hey uhm...if my answer stinks, would anyone care to tell me why?

Comment: You have said that "In US Southern speech (at least), you would ask the guests if they would like some watermelon, implicitly making the case that they will be having more than one slice, not more than one watermelon. " So, if I want the guests to eat as many as they want, I would say, "would you like some bananas?" Am I right?

Comment: The clearest thing is to tell the guests explicitly something like "Eat as much as you'd like."

Comment: Banana slices are plural. Is it right to say "Eat as much as you'd like"?

Comment: I upvoted your answer as good common sense. Note that anyone can DV without explanation or being cornered as to why, so asking why is not necessarily polite.

Comment: It was possibly because the question (or a very close facsimile) has been asked and answered before. The use of a noun in both count and non-count usages.